# How to fetch solr xml data with specific index and also with multivalues?

Tags: solr

In solr data stored like

```
<doc>
<str name="id">44</str>
<str name="age">1</str>
<str name="employer_id">33</str>
<arr name="languages">...</arr>
<str name="latlng">37.36883,-122.0363496</str>
<str name="occupation">6</str>
<arr name="payrange">...</arr>
<arr name="shift">...</arr>
<arr name="workschedule">...</arr>
</doc>
```

I want to search all data with occupation=5 payrange=8 or 9 or 10 and location bound with latlong.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the following resources for information on performing queries in Solr.

- [Solr Query Syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)
- [Common Query Parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)
- [Spatial Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch)

You should be able to accomplish what you are wanting by using filter queries and range queries for your occupation and payrange fields. You will most likely need to use the [geodist](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function) function for doing location bounding with latlong.